# How to set custom unwind segue animation in Attributes Inspector in Xcode 7.3.1

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to set a custom unwind segue animation through my storyboard in Xcode 7.2.1. If I select my unwind segue in the Document Outline, I see that there is a Class option available in the Attributes Inspector to supply a UIStoryboardSegue class. However, when I set my custom segue class there and I run my app I get the following error:

***Error:***

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception `UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency`, reason: child view controller: `DestinationTableViewController` should have parent view controller:`SourceTableViewController`: but actual parent is:`UINavigationController: 0x12e8e9400`**

***Destination Table View Controller unwind segue code:***

```
@IBAction func unwindToCategoriesTableViewController(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
        //back to categories view
        if segue.sourceViewController is ServiceDetailsTableViewController {
            checkmarkLabel.hidden = false
    }
```

***Custom segue class:***

```
class CustomShrinkToCenterSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {

    override func perform()
    {
        let sourceVC = self.sourceViewController
        let destinationVC = self.destinationViewController

        sourceVC.view.addSubview(destinationVC.view)

        destinationVC.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1)

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.0, options: .CurveEaseInOut, animations: { () -> Void in

            destinationVC.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.05, 0.05)

        }) { (finished) -> Void in

            destinationVC.view.removeFromSuperview()

            let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(0.001 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))

            dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

                sourceVC.presentViewController(destinationVC, animated: false, completion: nil)

            }
        }
    }

}
```

***Attributes Inspector options when the segue is selected in the Document Outline***

[image]